# Codeigniter Flash Data not deleting

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My code is actually not deleting. I am checking if the $user_id variable is true or false. If true the user is logged in and redirected and if false then flash data is created showing not logged in.
The problem is that once created flash data is not disappearing I am returning number of rows from model in $user_id variable

```
 $user_id = $this->login_model->login($email,$password);
 if($user_id == true){
    $user_data = array("user_id"=>$user_id,"email"=>$email,"loggedin"=>true);
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success','You Are Now Logged In');
    redirect('dashboard');
 }else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed','Email Or Password Is Incorrect'); 
 }
```

Here is my model code:

```
$query =$this->db->where('email',$email);
$query =$this->db->where('password',$password);
$result = $this->db->get('users');
   if($result->num_rows() == 1){
      return $result->row(0)->id;
      }else{
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: The model code is irrelevant to your question. How are you displaying the flashdata?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Flashdata not getting cleared in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846462/flashdata-not-getting-cleared-in-codeigniter)
You may try some solutions given in this question. They should work.

Comment: show your view page

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the `flash_data` **disappear** or **fade** you need to create a script for that.

use this to disappear your **flash_data**.

```
setInterval(function()
  {
     $('#flash_data').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 3000);
```

set the interval and in your **html code** do this...

```
<?php if(($this->session->flashdata('name')=='Hello, I am Flash Data')){?>
     <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" id="flash_data"> //set your id here
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('notif'); ?>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 01**

In model you're passing `return $result->row(0)->id;` and checking `if($user_id == true){`. It won't ever go inside funtion **boolen != Intiger**.

Replace this

```
if($user_id == true){
```

to this

```
if($user_id != false){
```

---

**Step 02**

you have two ways in controller `if and`else`. Only one defined with`redirect`

```
if($user_id == true){ # Must change accroding to step 01
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success','You Are Now Logged In');
    redirect('dashboard');
}else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed','Email Or Password Is Incorrect'); 
    # missing ??? Maybe redirect('login');
}
```

Add `redirect` to `login` route and this will work.

---

1. Flash data can **use only ONCE**.
2. Flash data **works on browser REFRESH**.

Comment: Hi actually I have a problem i figured it out i am using form action on the same page that's why it is causing this error because flash data appears continously can you help me fix this?

Comment: if($this->session->flashdata('login_success')){
    echo $this->session->flashdata('login_success');
}elseif($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')){
    echo $this->session->flashdata('login_failed');
}

Comment: add in your question and add form as well

Comment: hi i fixed this via changing the action on an another page action="login/login_check" but can you tell me a way through which i can display the error on same page like in core php if(isset($_POST[''submit])){     echo error ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to disappear data.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#div_id").hide();
    }, 4000);
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you still find the solution, you can try my solution

Add onload js function at your body

```
<body onload="clearme();">
```

Add js script at your bottom before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearme() {
      <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['msg_success'])):
            unset($_SESSION['msg_success']);
        elseif (isset($_SESSION['msg_error'])):
            unset($_SESSION['msg_error']);
        endif;
     ?>
   }
</script>
```

it's will clear your flashdata session everytime you load new controller. it's work for me because your problem also nightmare for me before.

Comment: Why are you wrapping PHP code in javascript? While syntactically valid, it has no semantic relationship and will not executed by calling `clearme()`. Instead, PHP will execute the code while rendering the page, regardless of any javascript

Comment: It's working because you're executing the PHP code on page load, regardless. There's no reason to have any of the javascript or the onload call.